# how to exclude command window changes from redo (dot) in vim?

Tags: vim

I always use the command window instead of the command prompt.

I do this via the map

```
nnoremap : q:i
```

The Problem is: the changes made to the command buffer are then in the redo-register
(I'm not sure if that's the right term, pleas correct me).

E.g. whenever I do `:w<cr>` to save the file, the next dot I issue inserts a `w`.

Can I somehow forget the redoable commands made in the command window, when it closes?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a defined name, but "repeat register" or "repeat buffer" is pretty close. See `:help repeat.txt` and `:help registers`. Note that normally the command-line isn't included in the repeat register; this only happens when you go into the command-line editing window. I don't know how to work around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this could be done using CmdwinEnter & CmdwinLeave events (remembering what's the command to be repeated by "." on command window enter, and resetting that value on command window leave).

Unfortunately, I've found no way to programatically set the value for "the last command to be repeated by '.'"

So, to my understanding, currently there's no way to do this.

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps we could redefine the dot?

Comment: The point is: There's no (to my knowledge) programmatic access to the information of which the last normal mode command (the one "." will repeat) is. There exists the dot register (".), which contains the last inserted text, which is near to what we want. But that only contains the text, not the command (you don't know if it was a "i" or an "a"). And, moreover, the register is read-only. Therefor, you'd have to implement an infrastructure to remember each an every command issued, which seems overkill to me. So, I see no way to do it. But I'll be glad to know if somebody else knows better.

Answer (score 1):

That's unfortunately a side effect of using the command window: As you're using "real" Vim commands to edit your commands, these naturally are also stored for redo. As there's no way to temporarily suspend the recording of commands, you either have to live with this side effect, or switch to using the command-line for most Ex commands.

Comment: I understand why the behaviour is like that, but I somehow doubt that it can't be bent.

Comment: Not without a ridiculously contorted implementation (like wrapping all built-in Vim commands) or without a patch to Vim's source code.